# insert select statement with certain columns only

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

i am trying to insert data to table1 from 2 columns from table2.

table1 has 5 columns.c1,c2,c3,c4,c4

what i am doing now is

```
insert into table1(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5)select t1,t2,getdate(),NULL,getdate() from table2
```

no error returns. Return result was no rows were affected.
can anyone tell me how to insert 3 fix value for last 3 columns?

Comment: The INSERT statement should result in a syntax error. That it doesn't, indicates there is somthing wrong in your setup. What tells you the command was actually executed but affected no rows?

Comment: This *should* work - are there any rows in `table2` at all??

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
insert into table1(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5)
select t1,t2,getdate(),NULL,getdate() from table2
```

Comment: hi.i tried that same return results.no rows was affected

Answer (score 1):

It is columns you want to add, not tables, so simply re-position:

```
insert into table1(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5)
  select t1,t2,getdate(),NULL,getdate() from table2;
```

Comment: hi.i tried that same return results.no rows was affected

Comment: It is strange in the first place that you got no syntax error on your own insert statement. So maybe something is wrong in how you invoke this command. Above statement should result in "no rows affected" only when table2 is empty.

Comment: there is 200 records in table 2

Comment: Okay, then maybe your command is not being executed, so of course nothing happens. How do you invoke the INSERT command? Do you use a tool or a programming language?

Comment: hi i just check my query. my syntax is wrong. i have a where statement behind with != NULL. should be is not null

Answer (score 1):

You will have to make it part of the select query

```
insert into table1(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5)
select t1,t2 ,getdate(),NULL,getdate() from table2
```

Comment: @vbCoder, that's certainly not possible. Did you ran the entire query?

Answer (score 0):

isntead of 
`insert into table1(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5)select t1,t2,getdate(),NULL,getdate() from table2 != NULL`

i change to

```
insert into table1(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5)select t1,t2,getdate(),NULL,getdate() from table2 is not null
```

sorry for the mistake guys